# Applying img-fluid by css or universally for database supplied images

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap site being used as a CMS so that a user can choose a layout and drag images into DIV containers, which are bootstrap columns, and save them to be displayed on digital displays.

I've got most things working but if they drag a huge image into the column it breaks out of the column and I want to apply the `img-fluid` class to any image that might be supplied into the template from the database

The issue obviously is I don't have hardcoded images, they're saved in the database and wrapped in HTML.

How can I apply the class universally to all images?

here's an example of a template that's used

```
html,
        body {
          height: 100vh;
          width: 100vw;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
img {
          max-width: 100%; 
          height:auto;
          margin:0 auto;
        }
.fullContent{
          display:flex;
          justify-content:center;
          align-items:center;
        }
.my-container {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
          height: 100vh;
          width:100vw;
        }


<div class="container-fluid my-container d-flex h-100">
    <div class="row middle" id="middle">
        <div class="col-lg-12" id="fullColumn">
            <div class="fullContent" id="fullContent" style="height: 100%; ">
              <!--an image would be here-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new selector and put the `.img-fluid's` rules in it. like below.
CSS:

```
.fullContent > img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

If you are using SCSS just do this

```
.fullContent > img{
       @include img-fluid;
}
```